# foundation reveal top position different for on modal only

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

Our default top position for a modal window using Foundation Reveal is 100px.  I don't want to change that, except for one specific modal which needs to be 40px.

How would I do that?  Current open call looks like this:

```
$('#pgquickview-modal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
```

Comment: Can't you just make a CSS rule: `#pgquickview-modal {top: 40px;}`?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  Though it would work.   But our modals "slide down" as they fade in, and this stops the sliding action.  For now I have done that with an `!important` directive on the 40px, but wonder if there is a 3rd param to pass in .foundation( .. )

Comment: Is this Foundation 5 or 6?

Comment: `alert(Foundation.version);` - 5.2.2